# Android, Unable to write a serializable object , .data file does not appear

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm trying to persist an serializable to Android's storage, although there are no security,permission errors/exceptions or any other error, the object file(.data) file does not appear???

Here is the relevant code snippet, refer to the **writeObj(File writePath) method**:

```
package experiment.xyz.eegdatacapture;


/**
 * DelimitedReport records & ouputs delimited report
 */
public class DelimitedReport implements Serializable {



    private volatile List<Record> recordArrayList = new ArrayList<Record>();

    public void setCurrentRecord(Record currentRecord) {
        synchronized(this) {
            this.currentRecord = currentRecord;
        }
    }

    private Record currentRecord = null;

    public Record getCurrentRecord() {
        synchronized (this) {return currentRecord;}
    }

    public List<Record> getRecordArrayList() {
        synchronized (this){return recordArrayList;}
    }

    public Record createANewRecord(String recordTitle)
    {
        synchronized(this) {
            currentRecord = new Record(recordTitle);
            return currentRecord;
        }
    }


    public File getOutputPathFile() {
        return outputPathFile;
    }

    public void setOutputPathFile(File outputPathFile) {
        this.outputPathFile = outputPathFile;
    }

    private File outputPathFile;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;



    //duration of the data collection
    private long duration;

    public long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(long duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public byte[] getExperimentsBackgroundImage() {
        return experimentsBackgroundImage;
    }

    public void setExperimentsBackgroundImage(byte[] experimentsBackgroundImage) {
        this.experimentsBackgroundImage = experimentsBackgroundImage;
    }

    private   byte [] experimentsBackgroundImage;


    //write object to storage
    public void writeObj(File writePath)
    {
        FileOutputStream fis = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos=null;
        try
        {
                if (writePath!=null)

            {
                Log.i("EEGdataCapture","writeObj path: "+writePath.getAbsolutePath());
                fis = new FileOutputStream(writePath);
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fis);
                oos.writeObject(this);


            }
        }//end try
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
        finally {
            //cleanup

            if (oos!=null)
            {
                try {
                    oos.flush();
                    oos.close();
                    oos = null;
                }
                catch (IOException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (fis!=null)
            {
                try {
                    fis.flush();
                    fis.close();
                    fis = null;
                }
                catch (IOException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

}

    //read object .cfrom storage
    public DelimitedReport readObj(File readPath)
    {
        DelimitedReport delimitedReport=null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try
        {

            if (readPath!=null) {
                fis = new FileInputStream(readPath);
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                Object obj = ois.readObject();
                if (obj instanceof DelimitedReport) {
                    delimitedReport = (DelimitedReport) obj;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ois!=null)
            {
                try {
                    ois.close();
                }
                catch (IOException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fis!=null)
            {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                }
                catch (IOException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return  delimitedReport;
    }

}//end DelimitedReport class
```

The  **writeObj(File writePath)** is called from the GUI via an activity, see below snippet:

```
public class CreateNewDataCollectionTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button createButton;
    private  Button createStartButton;
    private Button cancelButton;
    private File defaultOutputPathFile = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.create_new_data_collection_task);
        final TextView TextViewOutputpath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewOutputPath);
        //TODO: change later to multiline
        TextViewOutputpath.setText(defaultOutputPathFile.getAbsolutePath());


        createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCreate);
        createStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateStart);
        cancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateTaskCancel);

        createButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final EditText EditTextTaskName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTaskName);
                final EditText EditTextDuration = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTaskDuration);

                int duration = 0;
                String name = EditTextTaskName.getText().toString();
                try {
                    duration = Integer.parseInt(EditTextDuration.getText().toString());
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();

                }

                if (name!=null && name.length() >0 && duration > 0) {


                    final DelimitedReport newDelimitedReport = new DelimitedReport();
                    newDelimitedReport.setName(name);
                    newDelimitedReport.setDuration(duration);

                    boolean  pathIsOk = FileUtil.createDirIfNotExists("/EEGdataCapture");

                    if (pathIsOk) {
                        final File DelimitedReportFile = new File(defaultOutputPathFile.getPath() + "/EEGdataCapture/" + newDelimitedReport.getName() + ".data");

                        //if the file does not exist , then just persist the object
                        if (!DelimitedReportFile.exists()) {
                            newDelimitedReport.setOutputPathFile(DelimitedReportFile);

                            //******CALLED HERE
                            newDelimitedReport.writeObj(newDelimitedReport.getOutputPathFile());
                            //alert task was created
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Task " + newDelimitedReport.getName() + " was created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            //a task with this name already exists the app replace it?

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateNewDataCollectionTaskActivity.this);

                            builder.setTitle("Confirm");
                            builder.setMessage("A task with this name already exists, should the app replace it??");

                            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    newDelimitedReport.setOutputPathFile(DelimitedReportFile);
                                   //******CALLED HERE
                                    newDelimitedReport.writeObj(newDelimitedReport.getOutputPathFile());
                                    //1st dismiss the confirmation
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                    //alert task was created
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Task " + newDelimitedReport.getName() + " was created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();

                                    //empty text fields in case another task needs to be created
                                    EditTextTaskName.setText("");
                                    EditTextDuration.setText("");
                                    defaultOutputPathFile = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                                    TextViewOutputpath.setText(defaultOutputPathFile.getPath());


                                }
                            });

                            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                    EditTextTaskName.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                                    EditTextTaskName.requestFocus();


                                    // Do nothing
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            alert.show();
                        }

                    }//end if path is ok & was created
                    else
                    {
                        //alert task was created
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Unable to make path, try another path.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //validation alerts
                        if (name==null || name.length()<1)
                        {
                            //alert
                            Toast.makeText(CreateNewDataCollectionTaskActivity.this, "Specify a task name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    if (duration<1)
                    {
                        //alert

                        Toast.makeText(CreateNewDataCollectionTaskActivity.this, "Specify duration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }



            }
        });
}//end activity
```

Relevant AndroidManifest.xml permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Im also asking checking whether the write permission was granted at runtime which it is.

When I check the Android file system I see that the floder is created but the file is not created???

Thanks

Comment: Did it print a stack trace?

Comment: You have no read or write access to `Environment.getDataDirectory()`. Also, you have no read or write access to `/EEGdataCapture`. Please use [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).